# Why ERR doesn't have access to a global variable

Tags: bash, shell, asynchronous

I have the simplest case with asynchronous execution (runs in the background):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# set-eE.sh

set -eE  # same as: `set -o errexit -o errtrace`

# global variable
PID=

# handle errors
trap errorfunc ERR
errorfunc(){
    echo "error PID=$PID"
}

function func(){
  cd nowhere
}

echo "func point"
func &
PID=$!
wait
echo "exit point PID=$PID"
```

Can't understand why I have the next output (pay attention to the empty `PID` under `trap`):

```
func point
./set-eE.sh: line 16: cd: nowhere: No such file or directory
error PID=
exit point PID=5464
```

So, there is two questions:

1. Why global variable `PID` is empty under `trap errorfunc ERR`
2. Why my script doesn't stop and works out to the end?
   Thanks you.

Comment: The error is happening before you assign `PID`.

Comment: @Barmar how to immediately exit from the execution in this case?

Comment: If you don't trap the error it exits. I'm not sure how to combine them.

Comment: That's a different problem from the question about the variable.

Comment: Adding a sleep to `func` doesn't solve the variable problem, so it's not just timing.

Comment: @Barmar No, it doesn't exit, just try and comment out the `trap`. I guess undocumented behavior caused by background `&`. If you just remove this async call, exits like a charm.

Comment: If you don't want the script to reach the last line, you should do `wait $PID`. `wait` alone will return zero there. It's all documented, there is nothing unexpected.

Comment: @oguzismail so, the error is happening after assigning the `PID` or before?

Comment: Either after, or before, we can't know for sure but that's not important here. `error PID=` you're seeing is coming from the subshell forked for executing `func` (because of `errtrace`), which has the empty copy of the variable `PID`, and has no access to the original its parent has anymore.

Comment: In `func &`, the `&` forces `func` to execute in a subshell; subshells get a copy of the parent shell's variables (as of the time they forked from the parent shell), but any changes after that point are completely independent. There's no such thing as a truly global variable in shell scripting -- all variables are local to a particular process.

Comment: @GordonDavisson looks like I need something like `trap 'kill %1' ERR` or `trap 'jobs -p | xargs kill -9' ERR` to be sure I kill child subshell? Because this is my real point to use `trap ERR`. And of course I need exit from the execution immediately.

Comment: Are you trying to have the parent kill the subprocess, or the subprocess kill the parent? At the moment, it's the subprocess that gets the error, and hence runs the trap; is it supposed to be killing its parent?

Comment: @GordonDavisson let's say, since `wait $PID` won't allow continuing the execution of the parent, all I need to do, is to verify no daemons/zombies continue executing, right?

Comment: I'm still not clear on what the actual goal is here.

Comment: @GordonDavisson sorry for the misunderstanding. I need that the script to stop its work after it has been raised (`func &`) any `ERR` (looks like `set -emE` in pair with `wait $PID` solves that stuff).  Also, as a teardown task, I need to kill all forked subshells in `trap ERR`

Comment: But the script did not raise ERR, the child process did. `I need to kill all forked subshells` there are none, `func` did not run any.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, processes are not threads. `&` creates a child process that has a **copy** of the parent shell execution environment **at the time** it is created. Changes in parent shell made after the child creation are not visible in child environment - these are separate processes.

> Why ERR doesn't have access to a global variable

It can access **its own** global variable and it's empty, as set by `PID=`.

> Why global variable PID is empty under trap errorfunc ERR

Because it was set to be empty with `PID=`.

> Why my script doesn't stop and works out to the end?

The main shell process does not stop because no command triggered `set -e` **in parent shell** - all commands exit with 0 exit status.

---

> I need that the script to stop its work after it has been raised (func &) any ERR

Then kill the parent shell from the child shell. As a quick and dirty hack you could kill the process group.

```
trap 'kill 0' ERR
```

A better solution would be to just kill parent

```
parent=$BASHPID
{ 
    trap 'kill $parent' EXIT
    func
} &
```

You could also wait specifically on the child `wait $PID`, which because the child exits with non-zero exit status, will return a non-zero exit status, which in turn will trigger `ERR` trap in parent shell.

> I need to kill all forked subshells in

Then you have to transfer context to parent shell and do the killing there. You could ex. send SIGUSR1 to parent shell and kill all child processes from the parent shell (or you can kill parent shell and kill all childs in EXIT trap of the parent shell). The child process has no idea about parent other childs, so it has to notify parent about the killing first.

See [this unix thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/609300/209955). Research about processes and shell environment and interprocess communication and process groups.

Comment: let me test and give you feedback. btw, thanks a lot.